# Multi-OS program compatibility

Tags: ios, linux, windows, ubuntu

Is it possible to create program that is compatible with all operating systems?
If not, what would be the best way to break it down and configure it to suit.

Comment: Yes.  If you only use functions defined in the C standard (C89 for the maximum portability), then your code can be ported to any system that supports standard C.  However, by modern standards, such programs tend to be unexciting; it is hard to write a GUI application that is fully portable, for example. So, you need to define what sort of program you want to write and what it will do.  Then you can consider how it might be adapted to each platform.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at QT http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/supported-platforms.html but it is not supported on iOS.